# Error 91 when using Find Function, Using ActiveCell?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the run time 91 error when I step through my code.
The point of the code is to use the ActiveCell(Which will be in Column H) to match a value in Column D, then look 4 cells to the right and copy the next 222 cells in the row. The destination is one cell to the right of the ActiveCell. I'd then like to clear the cell.

```
Sub MirrorUsers()
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WS1 = ActiveSheet
Set Rng1 = WS1.Range(WS1.Range("H2"), WS1.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Rng2 = WS1.Range(WS1.Range("D2"), WS1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Rng2.Find(What:=ActiveCell).Offset(, 4).Resize(, 222).Copy 
Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)

Rng1.Clear

End Sub
```

I expect values to mirror another rows values in specific cells. I am receiving a run time error 91 currently.

Comment: I feel like what I'm thinking would be related to a type-mismatch, not set to nothing error... but try definding your destination with offset and resize, or use `Range(Cells(activecell.row,12),Cells(activecell.row,12+222))` as the full destination range... and make sure they're on the same line... e.g. `Rng2.Find(What:=ActiveCell).Offset(, 4).Resize(, 222).Copy Range(Cells(activecell.row,12),Cells(activecell.row,12+222))`  ... I used col 12 as you said H + 4

Comment: You're assuming that the `Find` is successful. It might not be. `Dim myRng as Range`, then `Set myRng = Rng2.Find(What:=ActiveCell.Value)`. Then test `If Not MyRng Is Nothing` before attempting to `Offset` and `Resize`.

Comment: Find has many other parameters which you need to provide.  And you need to account for the possibility Find returns Nothing.  If the post is an exact copy of your code, Destination needs to be on the same line as Copy (or add a _)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 91 means your `Find` didn't find anything. Change your code to this

```
Set rFound = Rng2.Find(What:=ActiveCell)

Debug.Assert Not rFound Is Nothing

rFound.Offset(, 4).Resize(, 222).Copy _
Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)
```

and you'll see that `rFound` is `Nothing`. The error is that you're trying use the `Offset` property on a range that doesn't exist. You'll have to figure out why it's not finding it, but here are a few things to try:

First, when you use `Find` in code, include as many parameters as you can. If you change a parameter in the UI Find Dialog, it persists. So you may be searching for Entire Cell Contents when you don't want to. Or you maybe looking in Formulas when you want Values.

Make sure there are not trailing spaces or other nonprintable characters that are preventing a match.

Make sure that numbers are numbers and text is text and that you don't have a mix where you have text that merely looks like it's a number.